# How can I make alert backgrounds solid in Bootstrap 5.3.0 using SASS?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I want to compile my bootstrap css so that the background colour of my alert boxes are a solid colour rather the washed-out variant. E.g. I want the background colour of alert-danger to be the same colour that I set for $danger, not a lighter tint of it. Is that possible to do in the SASS? I appreciate that the same result could be achieved using bg-danger but I need to use the existing mark-up which uses the alert classes.

If it’s possible what is the variable. I thought it would be $alert-bg-scale but overriding that in my SASS variables seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this do, for example?

Before:

```
--bs-alert-bg: var(--bs-primary-bg-subtle);
```

After:

```
--bs-alert-bg: var(--bs-primary-bg);
```

You can also do overrides in your custom stylesheet: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/alerts/#variables

There's quite a bit of info on this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/alerts/#css